# How should a web developer approach building a Browser toolbar?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, browser-extension

I am a web developer looking to build a browser extension. What is the best way to build browser extensions using web technologies (HTML, Javsacript, etc). We are targeting IE and Firefox only. Can IE browser toolbars be created using HTML/Javascript?

Comment: Are you looking to build a browser extension or a toolbar? In that respect @WTP'-- is right. Try to avoid using a toolbar if you can, they usually open a new process (ie, ff, chrome and safari), annoy the users and slow down their system. There are several platforms that will enable you to build cross-browser extensions as the person below me noted :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of confusion here. Your question title says you are looking to develop a "Browser Toolbar", but in the question body itself you are asking about "Browser Extensions".

Its important to understand that in general Browser Toolbars are a subset of a Browser Extension. If you are indeed looking though to develop a Cross Browser Extension and **not** a toolbar I would really recommend the use of [Crossrider - a development framework for cross-browser extensions](http://crossrider.com).

They do not allow you develop toolbars, but they do have an online IDE and an extensive API to build cross-browser extensions for Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox and Safari with basic knowledge of JavaScript and jQuery.